# How to annotate count based on nested JSONField in Django 1.11 and postgres 9.6

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My model currently looks like:

```
class Review(models.Model):
      source = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
      metadata = JSONField(default=dict)
      entity_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Example queryset of class Review:

```
[{
  "id": 123,
  "source": "amazon",
  "entity_type": "media",
  "metadata": [
    {
      "product": 123456
    },
    {
      "product": 012345
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 1234,
  "source": "amazon",
  "entity_type": "media",
  "metadata": [
    {
      "product": 123456
    },
    {
      "product": 12345
    }
  ]
}]
```

I want to annotate count based on "source", "entity_type", "metadata_product"

I am talking about Django query similar to:

```
Review.objects.filter().values(
 "source","entity_type","metadata__product"
).annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

which will obviously not work.

I want to get output query set similar to:

```
[{"source": "amazon", "entity_type": "media", "metadata_product":
  123456, "count": 2}, 
 {"source": "amazon", "entity_type": "media","metadata_product":
  012345, "count": 1},
 {"source": "amazon", "entity_type": "media","metadata_product":
  12345, "count": 1}]
```

I want to achieve this using Django ORM and not resort to python because the table contains data close to 10 or 20 million.
If that is not possible it will be really good if someone can suggest raw SQL query which can be put in Django ORM raw SQL method.

Comment: The `count` annotation should count what? The way you describe the end result, count would always be 1. So I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @dirkgroten I gave an example of one record, there will be millions of records like that with different product id's, I want to get counts of reviews with the source, entity_type, and product id. You can think of this as getting a control total.

Comment: It would have helped to expand your example so we can understand when a count = 2 would happen. So what you say is you want to aggregate by the combination of source, entity_type and product?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes. Updated the question. My Bad.